# Does Moodle let you branch based on student's answers?

Tags: website

Does Moodle (www.moodle.org) let you branch based on the answers given to questions?  For example, I want to branch to section A if the student gets question 1 right.  If the student gets question 1 wrong, I want to branch to section B.

Comment: questions about websites and web applications like Moodle are offtopic on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean in Quizzes, Surveys, Lessons or some other module?

Lessons definitely can be done conditionally, I think surveys can too, but I'm not sure about quizzes.

Register at [Moodle's site](http://moodle.org/) and either check the documentation or ask on one of the Forums (Fora?) there.